# Error firebase: signInWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Estoy hace horas intentando resolver un error al logearme utilizando Firebase como backend, el error es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve leyendo otras publicaciones al respecto, pero son casos muy distintos donde lo resuelven de distintas formas, ¿Alguien tiene idea cual es la solucion a mi problema?

El problema se da al darle click al boton de Ingresar, el codigo del boton es el siguiente:

```
<button onclick="access()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
```

Y aca esta la funcion a la que lleva presionar el boton

```
function access(){
var email2 = document.getElementById('email2');
var pass2 = document.getElementById('pass2');


firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email2, pass2)
  .then((user) => {
    // Signed in
    // ...
  })

      .catch((error) => {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
      });
    
    
      }
```

(Firebase me lo tabea mal)

Y por si lo necesitan, aca esta el formulario:

```
<form>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Correo Electronico</label>
          <input id="email2" type="email" class="form-control">
          <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Contraseña</label>
          <input id="pass2" type="password" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      <button onclick="access()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
```

Muchas gracias a todos, si logro avanzar, actualizare el post

Saludos!

Comment: Envías un email válido?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al hacer lo siguiente:

```
document.getElementById('email2');
```

Estás obteniendo como resultado un [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) y no el valor de dicho elemento. Para acceder al valor debes hacer uso de la propiedad `value`:

```
document.getElementById('email2').value;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jonatan!